# Salesforce1 opening browser instead of App for Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, android, salesforce1-platform

I have an Android specific issue where if I have the user open up a VisualForce page in Salesforce1 it opens to the Browser.  This does not happen in iOS.  I went into the application settings and made sure that the default program to open is SF1 when opening a .salesforce and .force.com URL.

Below is the VisualForce code.  It’s opening to a specific list view:

```
<apex:page action="/{!$ObjectType.activity__c.keyprefix}?fcf=00Br0000000U3NO"/>
```

Comment: Does this happen for all android users/ specific user on android? Did you get a chance to test with a few others and see if this behavior is consistent?

Comment: It's pretty consistent across an S3 and S6.  Waiting on a Note S7 today.  I've also got a call in with Premier support

Comment: Did you by any chance check this :https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf1_turn_off_mobile_web_redirection.htm&language=en_US did you check if the users accidentally selected full site and may be thats why the page is redirecting all time to the browser instead of the app

Comment: @tjcinnamon Did you end up resolving this issue? Recently came across similar behavior.

Comment: That Project got decommissioned.  I’ll check out my code when I get back to the office tomorrow

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much!

Comment: I can't find anything.  I'm looking at my premier support case.  Did you try the solution that @Rao noted?